# How can I update the text on a label after each entry in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I currently need some way to refresh the text on a label after each entry in an input field. For example, my current label is "please input name" and a button that says "enter". Once the user inputs their name and clicks enter, I want the label name to change to "please enter age". I would repeat this process 6 times. Do I have to use some sort of loop for this?

Comment: This is a very user-unfriendly interface - you should simply have six input fields, that the user can enter in whatever order is convenient for them, and go back to correct previous entries if they notice a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

How I would do this:

1. create a list with all your labels.
2. define a function for the button click that (I) updates a counter and (II) sets the label to the index (the counter) of the list.

something like this:

```
myLabels = ["This is label 1", "This is label 2"]
btn = Button(root, text="OK", command=onclick)
counter = 0

def onclick():
    counter +=1
    myLabel.config(text=myLabels[counter])
```

Comment: Btw this will raise an error unless the `onclick` definition is at the top. Also you will need `global counter` at the start of `onclick`